# getting RSA private key from public key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

i'm studying up on RSA and looking at some toy examples.

I have written this toy example down in python code, with comments to follow along:p = 11

```
p = 11 
q = 3

n = p * q # 33 

phi = (p - 1) * (q -1) # 20

#and I choose e to be 3

e = 3
```

Now, I want to compute the secret key. I thought that this would be the way to do it, since I saw it on a lecturers slide:

```
d = (e**-1)  % phi
```

This also does make sense to me, since e and d are defined as:

```
d * e = 1 mod phi
```

when I calculate this however, I get 0.3, and it doesnt really make sense to me that the secret key would not be a integer.

Another thing I then started wondering about was the "d * e = 1 mod phi" definition, 1 mudulo anything is always 1, so could'nt the definition just as well be:

```
p * e = 1
```

Which doesnt really make sense to me either.
Where am i misstepping here?

Comment: What you are looking for is [modular inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: So d is the modular inverse of e?

Comment: d and e are modular inverses of each other, mod phi.

Comment: By the way, in python 3.8 or later, `pow()` can be used to compute modular inverses, e.g. `d = pow(e, -1, phi)`

Comment: ok, this makes sense, thx

Comment: How about my question regarding ´d * e = 1 mod phi´ being ´d * e = 1´ I really cant wrap my head around why "1 mod phi" should not be a redundant statement

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right place for a tutorial on modular arithmetic. There should be plenty of resources elsewhere.

Comment: You forget one crucial step; `GCD(e, phi(n)=1` must be hold.

Comment: You can use Carmichael's totient lcm(p-1,q-1), commonly notated lambda, instead of Euler's (p-1)x(q-1). This is explained in Wikipedia, and several dozen Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX. Although real implementations since about 1980 use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) with d mod p-1 and d mod q-1, as also explained in Wikipedia. In short, look at Wikipedia.

Comment: @kelalaka i'm pretty sure this holds?

Comment: [RSA steps](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88368/18298), if I've told you that first the `e` chosen than the primes? Yes while looking for the inverse you may check that, that will complicate the code, though.